# Raw partition recovery without data loss

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, partition-recovery, testdisk

I had a dynamic disk and in order to get back to MBR I have used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTL3JRv7Edg) but instead of getting back to NTFS, I now have a RAW filesystem. Using Testdisk, I am getting *Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.* when I try to list files, any way to recover them.

PS: Some article suggest using a data recovery tool, the problem that it would change date created and modified of folders and probably which is not desirable in my case.

Steps taken:

**In Disk Management**, right click and convert to MBR disk, and go through with it.

Use Minitool PW to restore partitions, it worked but the data partition was RAW.

I tried TestDisk and Minitool and always got the mentioned error.
So I formatted the disk and tried to get my files back but instead, I've gotten filenames like *File_0001.ext*.

To the best of my knowledge, I haven't written anything on the drive so theoretically what was done could be reversed.

Comment: Data recovery tools will likely lose all filename & folder hierarchy information, then present you with just a list of files with a number & extension. FILE001.jpg etc.

Comment: Could you also list the exact steps you took, to save people having to watch 5 minutes of youtube video in order to extract data that could be read in 20 seconds. It also will help to keep this question useful should the linked video ever disappear.

Comment: According to your post, you have written to the disk when you formatted it. When doing a recovery, it is always best to make a block image of the disk and work with the copy. A disk recovery tool will not change the timestamps on the files.